# как Запустить 2 функции одновременно?

Tags: javascript

есть ли какой-либо способ вызвать сразу 2 функции при перезагрузке страницы?

Answer (score 3):

Да, способ есть.

```
func1();
func2();
```

Comment: )))) Ааххаах. И ведь не поспоришь )

Comment: не поспоришь )!

Comment: @seanomallez, что не так с этим способом?